# Sanity Check Microsoft Graph API and Generating OAuth Token from Postman

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I am coding against the `Microsoft Graph API` and I am trying to proof out the ability to generate an OAuth Token. I am using Postman and have my application hosted on `Azure Active Directory`. I am running into an issue in Postman when trying to pass in the correct `Scopes` - I am trying to pass in `User.read` however, Postman is not generating a Token.

My Settings:

Auth URL: https://login.windows.net/{my_tenent}/oauth2/authorize

Access URL: https://login.windows.net/{my_tenent}/oauth2/token

Scope: User.readAll

Are these the correct values to be passing in to generate an OAuth Token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're mixing a bit of v1 and v2 endpoints here. I've written up a [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) that might help you out here.

The URI for authentication with v2 should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/` rather than `https://login.windows.net/{my_tenent}/oauth2/authorize`.

When requesting scopes with Graph, be sure and use the full URI and not just the scope name itself. For example, `user.read` should be requested as `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`. Multiple scopes are space delimited so requesting `user.read` and `mail.read` would be formatted as `"https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`.

If you would prefer to use the v1 Endpoint, you do not request scopes as part of the OAUTH workflow. With v1, scopes are defined in Azure Active Directory when you register the Application.

If you're not sure which to use, take a look at [Deciding between the Azure AD and Azure AD v2.0 endpoints](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview#deciding-between-the-azure-ad-and-azure-ad-v20-endpoints). In general, I tend to recommend v2 as it will eventually replace the legacy v1 implementation. There are however some older APIs (EWS, SfB, etc) that only support v1 at the moment so there are cases where your choice is made for you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you make sure to set up your application to request permissions to the Microsoft Graph?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications

The "permissions to other applications" section. You must statically select the scopes you want your application to call Microsoft Graph with, unless you are using the V2 endpoint which supports dynamic consent.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I fought with this same issue for nearly a day before finally figuring it out. These are the settings that work for me:

- Token Name: [anything you want]
- Auth Url: https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
- Access Token URL: https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token?resource=https://outlook.office365.com/ (although, I don't think the refresh works)
- Client ID: [your app's client id]
- Client Secret: [your app's client secret]
- Scope: I have a bunch of scopes in here, but they seem to be ignored. Scopes should be set in the app console
- Grant Type: Authorization Code
- Check "Request access token locally"

If everything works, you should get the login screen when you click "Request Token"

Comment: The reason Scope is being ignored is that you're calling into the older v1 endpoint. Scopes are only defined dynamically with the v2 endpoint.